# Why do nested components not have access to inherited properties?

Tags: angular, inheritance

I have a project in which I have a set of components which extend each other and inherit properties from child to parent ([base class]Certification -> [abstract class]Application -> [bottom of inheritance]Individual_Types).  This all works fine but the bottom component contains multiple nested components and I would like to share some of these inherited properties with the nested components.

If I try to use one of those inherited variables in a property binding I get an error of "Error TypeError: Cannot read propterty 'Id' of undefined." but if I instead set a member variable in the individual_type component and set it to the inherited property in the constructor then I can use that member variable in the binding with no error.

In Applications component:

```
export abstract class ApplicationComponent extends CertificationComponent implements OnInit {

  protected BaseAppType: AppType;
  protected BaseAppId: string;

  // Injected Services
  protected AppRouter: Router;
  protected AppServ: ApplicationService;


  constructor(private AppInject: Injector,
              private AppCertId: string, 
              private AppTypeId: string,
              private AppSumId: number) { 
    super(AppInject, AppCertId);
    this.AppRouter = AppInject.get(Router);
    this.AppServ = AppInject.get(ApplicationService);
    // Default AppType - BaseAppType actually set in ngOnInit
    this.BaseAppType = new AppType();
  }
```

Bottom of inheritance example:

```
export class NewBcabaComponent extends ApplicationComponent implements OnInit {

    private ParentAppType: AppType;

  public constructor(NewInject: Injector) { 
    super(NewInject, '2', '1', 11);
    this.ParentAppType = this.BaseAppType;
  }
```

Example Template with nested component

This works:

```
<div class="open-card-BG" *ngIf="CurrentPage == 1">
    <instructions [InstAppType]="ParentAppType"></instructions>
  </div>
```

This doesn't:

```
  <div class="open-card-BG" *ngIf="CurrentPage == 1">
    <instructions [InstAppType]="BaseAppType"></instructions>
  </div>
```